# Setting processing color affects whole window color

Tags: colors, processing, hsb

I'm making a processing application in which some data is interpolated in a separate thread from the main one. In this new thread, I have the line `color aColor = color(255-(255*_hue[0]), 255, 255);`. (the colorscheme is HSB).

This line causes the screen to flash red. It seems the line (who's variable `aColor` is *never* used) is causing some serious colour changes in the application window. There is no image being drawn or anything.

I am wondering if this is some sort of bug with processing, if there is a solution, or even if there is a workaround. Thanks

Comment: Can you post a bit more code that's easy to test ? I'm suspecting you are calling `fill()` somewhere from your `draw()` loop

Comment: I'll post code when I get back to my laptop, but yes I have fill() in my draw, how can I get the same effect without it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Regardless of wether you use the `aColor` variable or not, you must be using `fill()` somewhere from your `draw()` loop.

By default fill() works globally: all subsequent shapes that will be drawn after a fill() call will have that colour.

To isolate fill() calls so they affect shapes drawn locally, not globally, you need to isolate such fill() calls within [pushStyle()](http://processing.org/reference/pushStyle_.html)/popStyle() calls.

```
fill(192,0,0);//set global fill to red
rect(0,0,50,50);

pushStyle();
fill(0,192,0);//set local fill to green
rect(50,0,50,50);
popStyle();

rect(50,50,50,50);//draw using last global fill: red
```